# How do I display only the number currently in cart?

Tags: php, html, magento2, cart

I am trying to display the number of items currently in my cart, however not getting any result. In Magento 1 we just just add the following to our phtml file and it will just echo the no. of items in cart.

```
Mage::getModel(‘checkout/cart’)->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
```

This of course does not work in in Magento 2 (version 2.0.2). Within my custom HTML file. I just need to "echo" just the number, just like you get when get a number on the mini cart.

This is the section of code I need to put it in:

```html
<span class="cart-text"><strong>Basket:</strong>
    <span class="cart-count">??????</span> item(s)
</span>
```

I need to put the number in replace of the question marks.

Comment: $cartItemsCount = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount(); Try this

Answer (score 2):

To display the items currently in cart you have to use the below code

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
echo $helper->getItemsCount();
```

So my complete code looks like this:

```
<span class="cart-text"><strong>Basket:</strong>
    <span class="cart-count">
    <?php 
        $helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
        echo $helper->getItemsCount();
    ?></span> item(s)
</span>
```

Just posting this as a reference to myself and others.

Comment: This always returns 0 for me

Comment: In my case this works only on the cart page @Zsolti how did you manage to fix it mate?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$cartItemsCount = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

Comment: Thanks @Naveenbos, However the code was returning error, but i have posted the code used to solve my issues. Thanks